# any ideas why facebook like button do not display non-English letters on a wordpress blog?

Tags: facebook, html, wordpress

All non-English (Lithuanian) elements like š,ė,ž,č and more are displayed as code which doesnt look nice. I added a facebook like button to my wordpress blog, which looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=lt_LT&href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; position: relative; top: -150px; padding: 0 0 20px 0; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:60px"></iframe>
```

You can see that I added `locale=lt_LT` (I'm from Lithuania)

DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Im using this:

```
<?php
    $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_thumbnail_id',false);
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb[0], false);
    $thumb = $thumb[0];
    $default_img = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/default_icon.jpg';

    ?>


    <?php if(is_single() || is_page()) { ?>
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?>" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php
        while(have_posts()):the_post();
        $out_excerpt = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", get_the_excerpt());
        echo apply_filters('the_excerpt_rss', $out_excerpt);
        endwhile;   ?>" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php if ( $thumb[0] == null ) { echo $default_img; } else { echo $thumb; } ?>" />
    <?php  } else { ?>
        <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
       <meta property="og:title" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="<?php  if ( $thumb[0] == null ) { echo $default_img; } else { echo $thumb; } ?>" />
    <?php  }  ?>
```

Can it be a problem with DOCTYPE or something else?

Comment: The URL of your website will dismiss many additional questions.

Comment: www.techgeek.lt  I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your test editor is saving the source file in wrong encoding. Please check that it is saved as a valid UTF-8.

Comment: Laurent, what do you mean by "test editor" and any tips of what to check?

Comment: I saved header.php and single.php as UT8, but it didnt help

Comment: that is strange because when i'm viewing the source code of your index page i see non UTF-8 characters. Also as a sidenote, there are some errors at your page (js and 404s).

Comment: on site its fine, it doesnt show correctly on facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, for like button, try using fb developer page and get the code for htlm5; instead of iframe. i made like button in spanish some time ago, let me check my code. i'll get baack to you.

Comment: add this to your `<head>`

`<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>` 

 //////// and this where you want your like button ///////

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.techgeek.lt" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

Comment: I did everything what you said and it didnt help.

Comment: but i can see the button with Patinka, and lt text after.

Answer (score 2):

The language of the button sets when you order a button from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
the button should have the language according to the user. example

```
js.src = "/ / connect.facebook.net / es_LA / all.js # xfbml = 1 & appId = 250867014982684";
```

that line where it says you can modify for your code es_LA language. This is html 5.